# Yii 1.x, CDetailView - how to not display only one attribute from many?

Tags: yii, cdetailview

I have model with many fields and I have "view" action to show detailed informations. In this view, I want to display all field without one, how can I do this? Do I have to write all fields in "attributes" array without that one which I don't want to show?

//Edit: I'm using CDetailView to show one specific record. I want show all fields from that record without one specific field, e.g. ID of record.

PS. Sorry for my English, I'm not native English speaker.
Regards

Comment: Unclear what you are asking and add sample code to create understandable example.

Comment: What is unclear here? I have model, model have e.g. 20 fields. I have Action to show one instance of that model, one specific record, but I want to show all fields without one specific field e.g. ID of record in mongoDB database (which is hexadecimal string).

Comment: Yes you must write all the attributes you want dsplay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write all fields in "attributes" array without the one which you don't want to show in CDetailView.

Let me know if there is any concern/query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
'attributes' => [
    [
        'title' => 'Your title',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => $model->id . '  ' . $model->name, // you can use html and other formatting options here
    ],
]
```

For more info look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView